# How to remove cwm and unroot tab 2 10.1

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

For my introduction into Android I picked up a cheap tab 2 10.1 from Amazon as it was stuck in a boot loop.

After searching this forum I found a post related to 'unrooting' the tablet, and so I was able to 'unroot' it by flashing it with a new rom. I used slimrom to test and now I'll use a factory rom next.

Could someone please instruct me on how to remove the cwm so that I can completely return the tablet to near factory-like condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to unroot Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 to stock official firmware

1. Download appropriate stock official firmware (according to region) for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 to computer.
   Download links: [GT-P5100](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-P5100)/[GT-P5110](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-P5110)/[GT-P5113](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-P5113)
2. Extract the downloaded zip to get a file with `.tar.md5` extension along with some other files
3. Download and extract [Odin3](http://dl.sammobile.com/Odin3-v3.11.1.zip)
4. Turn off the Galaxy tablet and wait for five to six seconds for vibration to confirm complete power off
5. Boot the tablet into Download Mode by pressing and holding Volume Down and Power buttons together until a warning screen appears on the tablet's screen. Now press the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button to continue to enter into Download Mode
6. Run Odin3 as Administrator
7. Connect the tablet to the computer using the USB cable while the phone is in Download Mode. Wait until Odin detects the device. When it is connected successfully, an Added message will appear under Odin's message box. Additionally, the ID: COM box in Odin will turn blue with COM port number indicating successful connection.
   Note: If the Added message does not appear, then try the USB port at the back of the computer. If Odin still fails to recognize the device then re-install USB Driver.
8. Select these files extracted from stock firmware folder to install on the tablet

   1. Click PDA button and select file with `.tar.md5` extension
   2. Click Phone button and select file with Modem in its name
   3. Click CSC button and select file with CSC in its name
   4. Click PIT button and select the `.pit` file
       
      Note: Ignore last three steps (2-4) if such files are not found.
9. Configure Odin settings. Ensure Auto Reboot and F.Reset Time checkboxes are selected. But uncheck Re-Partition option; select it only when `.pit` file is being used
10. Double check everything and click the Start button in Odin. The installation should begin now and would take a few minutes to complete
11. When the installation process is completed, the phone will restart automatically. Following this, a PASS message with green background will appear in a box at the extreme left of Odin indicating successful installation. Unplug the USB cable from the phone to disconnect it from the computer

As the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 boots up successfully, it should be unrooted and running on stock official firmware. Head over to *Settings>> About tablet* to verify the software version of the device.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. The Odin link takes me to "wheretowatch.com" and then redirects to "wheretowatchincanada.ca" which has absolutely nothing of value. I don't understand why that link was provided. I found Odin online and will get started on the process shortly.

Comment: Replaced the link in case this answer is seen by others who need it.